# Array não está mostrando os dados que deveriam estar lá

Tags: java, arraylist, lista-encadeada

Classe `Interface`:

```
switch(opcao)
{
    case 1:
    Usuario umUsuario = new Usuario();
    umUsuario.criarUsuario();
    break;

    case 2 :
    System.out.println("Busca de usuario");
    System.out.println("Forneça o cpf do usuario");

    Usuario buscaUsuario = new Usuario();
    buscaUsuario.buscarUsuario();  
    break;

}
```

Classe `Usuario`

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Usuario
{
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private List usuarios = new ArrayList();   

    public void setNome(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome ;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf)
    {
        this.cpf = cpf ;
    }

    public String getCpf()
    {
        return this.cpf;
    }

    public String getNome()
    {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void criarUsuario(){  
        Usuario u = new Usuario(); 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

        System.out.println("Digite o nome do usuario:");  
        u.setNome(input.nextLine());  

        System.out.println("Digite o cpf:");  
        u.setCpf(input.nextLine());     

        usuarios.add(u);  
        System.out.println(usuarios.size());   
    }  

    public void buscarUsuario(){  
        System.out.println("oi");
        System.out.println(usuarios.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < usuarios.size(); i++) 
        {
            Usuario busca = (Usuario) usuarios.get(i);
            System.out.println(busca.getNome());                      
        }
    }  

}
```

O primeiro método esta ok consigo criar usuários e salvar na minha lista, porém no segundo método `public void buscarUsuario()` onde por enquanto apenas quero listar todos os nomes de usuários ele não me retorna nada. Além disto me diz que a lista esta vazia. Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema aí é conceitual antes de mais nada, então qualquer solução do que está pedindo continuará errada, a solução real é jogar tudo isso fora e começar fazer de novo do jeito certo.

Não faz o menor sentido ter um *array* dentro de uma classe chamada `Usuario`, afinal lá tem um um usuário e não um monte deles. Ou a classe é sobre **um** usuário, ou ela é sobre uma coleção de usuários. Daí começa ter outros problemas. Você cria um usuário (o `new` e a chamada do [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) faz exatamente isto) e aí chama um método chamado `criarUsuario()`, isso também não faz sentido, o usuário já está criado e sem dados, o que já não fazia sentido. Aí cria um usuário de novo e manda buscar um usuário, que obviamente não tem nada, você acabou de criar, portanto faz menos sentido ainda.

Se criar uma classe usuário como ela deve ser onde ela só cuida do usuário individual, que o objeto seja inicializado por um construtor como deve ser, e que a interface com o usuário (no caso o uso do `Scanner`) seja separado e colocado na classe principal ou uma classe separada só para cuidar disso e não misturar com o usuário, aí começa ficar mais fácil entender o que o código faz, cada um com sua responsabilidade, e aí fica claro que esses métodos de criar e buscar não fazem sentido aí, que fazem parte de outra classe, e que usuário é um entidade própria, e tudo começa fazer sentido, inclusive porque não vai mais criar um usuário para mandar criar um usuário e não vai criar também para fazer busca.

Ainda tem outras coisas confusas na pergunta. O primeiro método é o `setNome()`, até dá para entender que não é sobre ele que está falando, mas é um indicativo que você não se preocupa com clareza e exatidão do que está definindo. O que lista encadeada tem a ver com o problema? Programar é se preocupar com isso, especialmente em orientação a objetos. Sem saber exatamente o que deseja, ou seja, sem entender profundamente o problema, a solução nunca sairá boa porque há problema no problema. Programar é mais sobre resolver problemas do que criar códigos.

Classe `Interface` não parece ser um bom nome e talvez, só talvez, e só para um exercício o *array* deveria estar nele (pode ser que queira uma solução mais complexa e mais próximo do que realmente se faz).

Comment: Entendo seu apontamentos e como disse **iniciante em java**, mas vamos la então o mais indicado é  criar uma lista de objetos do tipo Usuário na classe Interface e não na própria classe ?

Comment: Então para quem está iniciando talvez seja o caso de fazer algo mais simples primeiro. Já pensou nisso? Não estou afirmando, só dando uma dica que pode estar partindo para algo que não está na hora. Mas posso estar enganado. E é o que eu disse.

Comment: Pode dar uma olhada na mudança que fiz abaixo se conceitualmente é melhor desta forma? mais a frente irei incluir mais listas de outros tipos de objetos devo incluir na mesma classe ainda ? crio uma classe de listas ?o que é mais indicado ?

Comment: O site não funciona assim, você faz uma pergunta e recebe uma resposta, não é uma forma interativa que você vai arrumando e a gente vai ajudando, é diferente de um fórum, mas olhando por cima melhorou muito, e é provável que o problema citado não exista mais. Ainda há um problema que o usuário não está sendo inicializado, nçao tem um construtor. Para um exercício está bom, mas em casos reais é sempre muito mais complexo que isto. Dá para fazer o cadastro de usuários ser uma classe, mas simples assim chega ser exagero, a parte de tela poderia ser uma classe própria pra isto para separar do menu

Answer (score 0):

Conforme indicação do amigo acima mudei para o seguinte:

Classe interface:

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Interface
{    
    private List usuarios = new ArrayList();   

    public void menuPrincipal()
    {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.apresentaMenu();
        int opcao = entrada.nextInt();
        while(opcao!=5)
        {
            switch(opcao)
            {
                case 1:
                System.out.println("Cadastro de usuario");
                System.out.println("Forneça o nome");
                entrada.nextLine();
                String nome = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Forneça o cpf");
                String cpf = entrada.nextLine();
                Usuario umUsuario= new Usuario();

                usuarios.add(umUsuario);
                break;

                case 2 :
                System.out.println("Busca de usuario");
                System.out.println(usuarios.size());
```

Classe usuario:

```
public class Usuario
{
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;


    public void setNome(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome ;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf)
    {
        this.cpf = cpf ;
    }

    public String getCpf()
    {
        return this.cpf;
    }

    public String getNome()
    {
        return this.nome;
    }

}
```